# Not finding the name in the object

Tags: javascript, api

I'm creating a quote generator, and im trying to get the author. I'd think its **`response.originator.name`** but it pulls up an error.  [image]

Then i tried `response[1].name` and it just pulls up a undefined response

Here is the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.then` is used to get the result of a `Promise`, you can't just keep calling it to a execute another line of code.

[Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    quote.innerText = response.content;
    name.innerText = response.originator.name;
 })
 .catch(err => console.error(err));
```